# MySQL - increment values of several rows with one query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to update and increment values of several rows with one query?

I have a following table services:

```
id | name | count | created_at | updated_at
```

I want to update the count every time a user chooses some of the services in the search (this is done via GUI, and the user can choose one or more services, and I am getting the ids of the services).

I can perform a single query for each service when more than one is selected, but that doesn't seems to be very efficient.

Example:

I need to update 7 services at once and increment the count value for each of them:

```
UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 28

UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 29

UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 39

UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 44

UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 296

UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 294

UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 111
```

Is it possible to perform this update in one query?

Comment: Not sure i have a feeling you are looking for this `UPDATE table SET count = count + 1 WHERE ....` .. But hard to say without more details.. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: The question seem a bit broad. Depending what other language you substitute your SQL with, then yes, it is possible. You could use a loop to update your rows based on the ID's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i need to update 7 services at once and increment the count value for
>   each of them:

```
UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 28

UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 29

UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 39

UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 44

UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 296

UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 294

UPDATE services SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 111
```

> Is it possible to perform this update in one query?

Can be rewritten into one query.

**Query**

```
UPDATE 
 services 
SET 
 count = count + 1 
WHERE
 id IN(28, 29, 39, 44, 296, 294, 111)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
update table set `count` = `count` + 1
```

Above query will update all rows.
If you want to update specific row you can add where condition:

```
update table set `count` = `count` + 1 where name = 'searchText'
```

Comment: I can do that for a single row, but that is a single query. I want to avoid making ten queries (if ten services are selected).

Comment: You can have where condition to select 10 services at once

Comment: Please share sample data for more specific answer

Comment: @RaymondNijland - this is exactly what I need. Didn't know I can use WHERE IN within update. Thanks mate :)